# How to filter list or records from database based on dropdownlist selection change?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to select a Region on the dropdown and filter the list to show records that are from the selected region

This is the method I am using to filter the list. I am calling the same method in my jquery ajax function

```
    public IEnumerable<Sale> SortByRegion(string Regions)
    {
        var SortList = from a in db.Sales
                       where a.Region.Contains(Regions)
                       select a;

        return SortList.ToList();
    }
```

This is the function I am using jquery ajax in to call my mcv method that filters the list.

```
        function SortByRegion(Regions) {
            var Regions = $('#Regions').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("SortByRegion", "Sales")',
                url: '/Sales/SortByRegion',
                data: { Regions: Regions },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#Index').html(result);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, err){

                }
            });

<select name="Regions" id="Regions" onchange="SortByRegion()">
    <option selected="selected" id="PlaceHolder">---Please Select Region---</option>
    <option id="Central">Central</option>
    <option id="East">East</option>
    <option id="West">West</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You should add the error message you get from the posted code in the question body. Your original question led my to believe it was a JQuery problem :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your controller returns IEnumerable which will return string message containing type of result:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TypeOfYourSaleObject]
```

You have to change your controller response to ActionResult

and `return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Than you will have to rebind you dropdown list.
You could also move that dropdown list to partial view and return html as partial view with specific model.

You could change this to:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult SortByRegion(string Regions)
        {
            var SortList = from a in db.Sales
                           where a.Region.Contains(Regions)
                select a;

            return Json(SortList.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Add additional property to your ajax request:

```
dataType: "json"
```

and later rebind your select content with json result. If that's the way you would like to go.

Comment: Hi @LukaszBalazy I was actually getting that error before I realised I needed to change my method return type. I have since changed the method return type while keeping the same Jquery function and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look into `.change()` ?

https://api.jquery.com/change/

**Description**: *Bind an event handler to the "change" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element*.

```
$( "#Regions" ).change(function() {
  SortByRegion($(this).val());
});
```

This method is a shortcut for `.on( "change", handler )`

**EDIT** after more code: change your function from `function SortByRegion(Regions) {` to `function SortByRegion() {` since you are not passing any value to it.

Comment: I am using the onchange event when I bind the function to the dropdown. Please see edited question.

Comment: Maybe change your function from `SortByRegion(Regions)` to `SortByRegion()` since you are not passing any value to it.

Comment: I am passing the selected value back to the mcv method. I did try passing it by calling it in the dropdown selection using the following  line:  onchange="SortByRegion(this.value)"...... This did not work!

Comment: You are getting the value directly from the ID, no need to pass it. In Internet Explorer you must pass a value if the function is expecting one. Do you get any error message? Did you try to change `function SortByRegion() {` ?

Comment: Yes I did try it, and I get a blank screen with the following error: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ExcelFileUploadTest.Models.Sale]